# ANDROID - update status linked-in (in app's Background)

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am makeing one android app.

I have list of product.

If i choose one product at that time that product share on `Linkedin` with user name.

I want this like below code(sample code of twitter share). I want same for `Linkedin`.

```
private final static Handler mTwitterHandler = new Handler();
    private static SharedPreferences prefs;

    public static boolean TWEET_LOGIN = false;

    final static Runnable mUpdateTwitterNotification = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    public static void sendTweet(Context con, final String msj) {

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, msj);
                    mTwitterHandler.post(mUpdateTwitterNotification);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("dhaval-->send tweet:", ex.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();
    }
```

It is possible or not if yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `linkedin-j-android.jar` [download](http://db.tt/yQjhqeq3)

put this code in to `AsyncTask` for do in background

```
private void shareText_new() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
                    .newInstance(generalClass.APIKEY, generalClass.APISECRET);
            final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(
                    generalClass._Token1, generalClass._Secret1);

            client.postNetworkUpdate("hello DJ");
            System.out
                    .println("Your update has been posted. Check the LinkedIn site for confirmation.");

            System.out.println("Fetching your network updates of type:"
                    + NetworkUpdateType.STATUS_UPDATE);
            Network network = client.getNetworkUpdates(EnumSet
                    .of(NetworkUpdateType.STATUS_UPDATE));
            printResult(network);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("error share st--->", "" + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
```

reference link [checkit](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/source/browse/trunk/linkedin-j/core/src/examples/java/com/google/code/linkedinapi/client/examples/PostNetworkUpdateExample.java?r=197)

[fullCode](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-update-status-linked-in.html)